# How I can add an icon on header with center align in ionic?

Tags: css, angularjs, ionic-framework

How I can add an "ion-ios-arrow-up" icon on header with center align in my ionic app like my concept below?
[image: my concept]

Its my HTML template:

```
<ion-view cache-view="false" view-title="Historical HPP">
    <ion-nav-bar class="nav-title-slide-ios7 bar-assertive" ng-click="click()"></ion-nav-bar> 
 <ion-content class="has-header"> 
Hello
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Thanks before

Comment: Can you edit this: http://play.ionic.io/app/ac4063d18c09 and show the current output?

Comment: @ManojKumar: [this codepen](http://codepen.io/calendee/pen/wAmIo) similar my HTML template like above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just bind the title to the `$scope` variable

```
<ion-view title="{{title}}">
```

and in your controller

```
$scope.title = "Historical HPP <i class='ion-arrow-up-c'></i>";
```

Codepen [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NqYqGo). Is this what your looking for?